# Any way to have a vertical toolbar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, toolbar

I would like to have a vertical toolbar on the left side of my Firefox windows.
Not a bookmark bar, not the tabs, but a regular toolbar that I can drag buttons and elements to.

I've been looking for quite a while now, but have been unable to find anything.
Can it be done, whether through an addon or through editing some configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Vertical Toolbar addon. http://www.xuldev.org/verticaltoolbar/

Comment: Thanks! That didn't exist yet when I asked my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.I also asked Firefox support and they didn't answer.
So I guess the answer is that you can't at the moment.